# iphone -- Memory leak although ARC

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-management, xcode4.5

I am getting a memory leak although Automatic Reference Counting is enabled.

I did a little bit of debugging and fount out that the problem where the app gets this output:
`*** error: can't allocate region*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug`

I tracked it down to this point:

```
if (currentTime < 60) {
    currentTimeMin = 0;
    ct.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i:%i", currentTimeMin, currentTime];
}
if (currentTime >= 60) {
    currentTimeMin = 1;
    ct.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i:%i", currentTimeMin, currentTime -60];
}
if (currentTime >= 120) {
    currentTimeMin = 2;
    ct.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i:%i", currentTimeMin, currentTime -120];
}
if (currentTime >= 180) {
    currentTimeMin = 3;
    ct.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i:%i", currentTimeMin, currentTime -180];
}
if (currentTime >= 240) {
    currentTimeMin = 4;
    ct.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i:%i", currentTimeMin, currentTime -240];
}
if (totalTime < 60) {
    totalTimeMin = 0;
    tt.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i:%i", totalTimeMin, totalTime];
}
if (totalTime >= 60) {
    totalTimeMin = 1;
    tt.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i:%i", totalTimeMin, totalTime -60];
}
if (totalTime >= 120) {
    totalTimeMin = 2;
    tt.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i:%i", totalTimeMin, totalTime -120];
}
if (totalTime >= 180) {
    totalTimeMin = 3;
    tt.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i:%i", totalTimeMin, totalTime -180];
}
if (totalTime >= 240) {
    totalTimeMin = 4;
    tt.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i:%i", totalTimeMin, totalTime -240];
}
```

I think the problem is with the labels: ct and tt but I am not sure and can't seem to figure out why. Everything worked perfectly until a day ago when I experimented a bit with UITableVIews.

Best regards! Martin

Comment: Did you try the suggestion of adding the `malloc_error_break` breakpoint?

Comment: You're setting the same text 4 times.  Any reason for that?

Comment: stringWithFormat isn't itself going to create a problem.  Though could be that you've trashed the heap and stringWithFormat is where that gets discovered.

Comment: (Assume that currentTime is 60 and study how control will flow through your code.)

Comment: (And consider working with Java for awhile before you try to do any more with Objective-C.)

Comment: @Hot Licks: How does using java help someone learn objective-c debugging and memory management?

Comment: @Minthos - By helping them learn how to code `if` statements.

Comment: @Hot Licks: I've never seen any evidence that java is superior to objective-c for teaching if statements.

Comment: @Minthos - But it would eliminate a lot of distractions while learning the basics (which this guy clearly hasn't learned).  Objective-C is a terrible language for learning the basics.

Answer (score 3):

Is this code within a loop?  If it is, you need to put your code into an autorelease pool.

```
while(someStuff) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        //Your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you need to use an explicit autorelease pool? Because of the quantity of string objects being created? By default they'd all be placed in the main application pool. Sure, they might last longer than intended since the pool wouldn't be drained each pass through the loop, but they wouldn't appear as leaks, would they?

Comment: @Metabble If you create enough autoreleased objects in a loop, your app can run out of memory before the autoreleased objects are released. By using an explicit autorelease pool like this in a loop, you ensure that this isn't an issue. This was appropriate pre-ARC and with ARC. The objects aren't leaking, but without the autorelease pool in the loop, they just keep building up because the loop prevents them from being cleaned up in a timely fashion.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks for trying to explain. I didn't explain myself well enough. I am aware of the benefits of having an autorelease pool inside of a loop; instead of having all of the autoreleased objects released at the end they are released at the end of each iteration of the loop. I'm saying that while this may improve efficiency it does nothing to stop the memory leaks and thus is not an answer; it should be a comment. He's asking why he's getting memory leaks, not how to use autorelease pools inside loops to increase efficiency. It just confused me is all.

Comment: @Metabble The error the question asker is reporting is one you get when there is not enough memory available.  His code as-written should not leak, but if you are in a loop and creating autoreleased objects it could look like a memory leak even though it isn't.

Comment: @SimonGoldeen Ah, I see. That makes sense. Thanks for explaining. I should've seen the error and thought it through more.

Answer (score 0):

That bit of code should not cause a leak. Your error is elsewhere. Enable guard malloc and read about debugging and profiling objective-c.